# Can I have two different Resistance boons active at the same time?

Tags: open-legend, boons

This is the scenario:

- Round 1: invoke Resistance Precise
- Round 2: invoke Resistance Forceful, **don't** sustain Resistance Precise

> If you have a boon in effect and do not sustain it, the boon ends when your turn is over.

During round 2, Resistance Precise is still active until the end of my turn, together with Resistance Forceful. But the rule says

> While targets may be effected by different boons, **you may not stack the same boon multiple times**; if a second invocation of a boon would affect a character, they choose which boon to keep and which one to negate.

**Does this mean that I can't have two different Resistance boons active?**

Answer (score 2):

**It means exactly that.**

The [text of Resistance](https://openlegendrpg.com/boons/resistance) is pretty clear:

> When the boon is invoked, the invoker chooses one type of attack and
>   the target gains resistance to that type.

It's not that this is a family of boons.  There is no such boon as "Resistance Forceful".  There is only "Resistance".  Resistance is invoked, and the caster has some control over its effects.  If Resistance were to be invoked a second time over the target, they would get to choose which one to keep.